# Adversative sentences

Tags: meaning, prepositions, sentence-meaning

What do the bold parts mean? Or rather, I should say that I'm confused by the bold parts, and I'd like to know what the sentences mean, and what kind of flavor they have to them. And what does *win away* mean?

> (1) He ran away **on me**.
>
> (2) They *won* several games *away* **on us** already.
>
> (3) Today I’m pissed, so I will quit early for the day **on him** [e.g., my boss].

I suppose bold parts are related to some kind of adversity, because in the [same place](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.87.4865&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (pp. 33-34) the following sentences appear:

> (a) I (adversely) experienced his running away.
>
> (b) Due to our carelessness we (adversely) experienced their winning several
>   games away from us.

Do (1) and (a) mean the same? And do (2) and (3) mean the same? And still, what kind of flavor do these sentences have?

Comment: None of the sentences mean the same thing. And (1) doesn't say anything about *why* it happened or the results, so it cannot be equated with (1). Unless you mean to ask if *run away* is being used in the same sense?

Comment: Do you know what adversative actually means??

Comment: Please not: These are spoken utterances by not very good speakers. They sound like transcriptions of spoken words. Spoken words are often full of oddities. It sounds like chat rooms or stuff on social media that is badly expressed.

Comment: @Lambie The source of these sentences is given in my post. As for whether I know what adversative means, yes and no. I've read definitions in dictionaries, but I can't say that I'm very comfortable with this term.

Comment: 2 is a mess, but something similar could be expressed by saying "They have two games on us in the series."

Answer (score 0):

Example (1) means first, that he ran away, and second, that I consider that to be negative and I am hurt by it. It is more or less equivalent to (a).

Example (2) isn't idiomatic in English. If you drop the "away", it is closer. In any case, "on us" doesn't fit well there.

Example (3) isn't quite idiomatic, either. The expression "on him", to express an adverse action is colloquial and informal, and it should be close to the action it applies to.
If it were  "Í'll quit early on him.", that would be more idiomatic. The more detail you put between "quit" and "on him", the less understandable it becomes.

I don't see the adversative "on"+ pronoun structure mentioned in the dictionaries I looked at, but it is referred to in this paper:

[escholarship UC Berkely "affectedness constructions"](https://escholarship.org/content/qt9fx1c060/qt9fx1c060.pdf?t=nmp45p)
"Affectedness Constructions: How Languages Indicate Positive and Negative Events", Tomoko Smith.

This paper refers to "on-affectee" constructions, and gives multiple examples, starting with these:

page 91:

> 4.2.1  English on-affectee construction
> As mentioned earlier, English has the on-affectee construction, which expresses that the evaluator sees an event as bad for the affectee.  The following are some examples of the construction.
> (1) John’s bike broke down on him.
> (2) John ate the cake on me.
> (3) The store is going to close down on us."

There are further examples going through page 95.

The paper refers to "adversative" and "benefactive" as "affectedness constructions".

Comment: Do the two appearances of "on me" here https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMkH9.png also mean that I consider your actions to be negative and I am hurt by those actions? I tried searching for this meaning of "on" in various online dictionaries (to see more examples of using "on me"), but I didn't find anything.

Comment: @user91073  I don't see the on+pronoun "adversative" struture reflected in dictionaries, but I found a paper online that discusses "on-affectee constructions". Yes, the examples at the link in your comment have that sense of adverseness.

Comment: I have added a link to the  paper I found in my posted answer.

Comment: To win a game on us, to win an away game on us. Just piss-poor English. That said, where did the OP get these? I really don't think you can analyze as you have. Transcripts of speech are full of odd things.The name that linguist found for this is (affectedness construction) spooky bad. :) but does describe it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The adversitive effect is demonstrated in the OED:

> **On** (preposition)
>
> III.
>
> **From, of.**
>
> **III.27. After verbs of winning, gaining, taking by force, etc.: from.** *Obsolete*.
>
> eOE Romane genamon on him LXXXIIII scipa. -- translation of Orosius,
> History (British Library MS. Add.) (1980) iv. vi. 93 *[My trans: The
> Romans took from him 84 ships]*
>
> 1608 But what art thou That hast this fortune on me? -- W.
> Shakespeare, King Lear xxiv. 161
>
> 1671 All these boasted Trophies won on me. -- J. Milton, Samson
> Agonistes 470

The OED entry is marked as "obsolete", but it is not. Current English has "Have this drink on me" and many other phrases in the exact meaning of "from" that appears above, e.g. 2000 Many of the employees too would show a sizeable profit on their shares. -- R. W. Holder, Taunton Cider & Langdons xvii. 92

The etymology compares the old and modern Frisian, Dutch, and German "a[a]n", which is often used in exactly the same way.